# I want to import a Python3 function from a different folder with GLOBAL scope

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, scope, global

I am working in Python3.x on Linux Mint 21 and here is my directory structure:

```
└── main_dir/
    ├── all_files_dir/
    │   ├── a_files_dir/
    │   │   └── file_a.py
    │   ├── b_files_dir/
    │   │   └── file_b.py
    │   └── c_files_dir/
    │       └── file_c.py
    └── runner.py
```

Here is the content of file_a.py

```
def function_a():
    print("a ran")
    return "a return value "
```

Here is the content of file_b.py

```
def function_b():
    print("b ran")
    return "b return value "
```

Here is the content of file_c.py

```
def function_c():
    print("this function STARTS running!!!")
    result_of_function_a = a()
    result_of_function_b = b()
    results_of_both_functions = result_of_function_a + result_of_function_b
    print("results_of_both_functions", results_of_both_functions)
```

Here is the content of runner.py

```
from all_files_dir.a_files_dir.file_a import function_a as a
a() # This Works!

from all_files_dir.b_files_dir.file_b import function_b as b
b() # This Works!

from all_files_dir.c_files_dir.file_c import function_c as c
c() # This STARTS working and prints 'this function STARTS running!!!'
# This FAILS eventually!!!
```

Here is the error message:

```
a ran
b ran
this function STARTS running!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main_dir/runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    c() # This STARTS working and prints 'this function STARTS running!!!'
  File ".../main_dir/all_files_dir/c_files_dir/file_c.py", line 3, in function_c
    result_of_function_a = a()
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

*I understand that I can add imports to function_c():* But I want to import all functions with a GLOBAL scope instead so that I do not have to modify anything in all_files_dir and I want to modify ONLY runner.py

How do I import function_a() as 'a()' and function_b() as 'b()' and function_c as 'c()' into runner.py in such a way that they can all see each other in GLOBAL scope and use each other easily without having to modify function_c() by adding more import statements to function_c()??? I only want to modify runner.py but cant figure out how....

I tried

```
global from all_files_dir.c_files_dir.file_c import function_c as c
```

but that does not work either...

I also suspect that importing functions with a "global scope" is probably not the best practice, but that is what I want anyways because the code is for a small home project, not for a corporate production work compliance environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python there's no such thing as a truly "global" variable. A "global" variable in Python is just a name bound to the namespace of the module that defines it. Since every module has its own namespace, having the names `a` and `b` imported to the main module does not mean that the `file_c` module would magically inherit them when imported by the main module, which means that you also need the following lines in your `file_c.py`:

```
from all_files_dir.a_files_dir.file_a import function_a as a
from all_files_dir.b_files_dir.file_b import function_b as b
```

You can also use relative import in `file_c.py` if the relative paths to `file_a` and `file_b` will always be the same:

```
from ..a_files_dir.file_a import function_a as a
from ..b_files_dir.file_b import function_b as b
```

EDIT: If you would don't want the module `file_c` to have its own namespace but would rather run `file_c.py` as if it were included inline in the main program, you can simply read `file_c.py` as a file and execute its content with `exec` in `runner.py`:

```
with open('main_dir/all_files_dir/c_files_dir/file_c.py') as file:
    exec(file.read())
    c = function_c
c()
```

To prevent unnecessary pollution of the main program's namespace, however, you can pass to `exec` a dict as the `locals` argument to selectively access names that are defined by the execution of `file_c`:

```
with open('main_dir/all_files_dir/c_files_dir/file_c.py') as file:
    names = {}
    exec(file.read(), globals(), names)
    c = names['function_c']
c()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AbsoluteJointSandbox